# Configurar URL Amigavel no .htaccess

Tags: htaccess

Estou tendo problemas com a configuração do meu arquivo `.htaccess`.

Tenho a seguinte URL:

> www.dominio.com.br/artigo?leitura=primeira-postagem

E, desejo que ela fique assim:

> www.dominio.com.br/artigo/leitura/primeira-postagem

ou

> www.dominio.com.br/artigo/primeira-postagem

Obs.: Meu código usa um slug para gerar um link permanente, salvo no banco de dados, que é o nome da postagem.

Estou tendo problemas no uso das expressões regulares, ou melhor, na estrutura do *RewriteRule*, simplesmente não funciona.

Como resolver este problema?